# @Path regex maching string and opposite

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm developing a JAX-RS webservice and I want my service to look like:

`/service/{db}`  where db can be resources or books

`/service/{id}`  where id is anything except resources or books

I have set:

```
@Path(service/{db : (i?)(resources|books)(?-i)})
```

and then for the other case:

```
@Path(service/{db : (i?)(!resources|books)(?-i)})
```

But it didn't work. I have also try to set :

```
@Path(service/{db : (i?)(another)(?-i)})
```

But it is not working either.

Any idea?

BTW if for one case db is a string and for the other a number, it worked, but I need strings in both cases.

Edit: I'm using Resteasy.
I have also found [this link](http://javarticles.com/2016/01/jax-rs-path-expressions-example.html), but for me it's not working and always is displaying the mixed.

Edit(2): The solution proposed by Nicolas seems to work in Jersey but it's not working in Resteasy. It seems that there is some issue with overlapping regex, that it is not getting the more restricted first.

Comment: Maybe it vill be easier if you dispatch that request in your Java code?

Comment: @talex Yes, but I wanted to test it this way ;) You know, there is always space to learn jeje